# How to switch between VGA and HDMI for 7 inch display controller without OSD keyboard

Tags: pi-3

I have a 7 inch 800X400 display, with the controller board, but I don't have the switch keyboard or OSD panel, When I hook it with raspberry pi using HDMI or VGA or even composite cable, it shows VGA mode and no signal, blue screen.
I tried config.txt configurations but it doesn't work.

Or alternatively does someone have the pcb for the osd panel keyboard?

datasheet for controller board: http://www.vslcd.com/Specification/VS-TY2662-V1.pdf

[image]

Comment: the control panel looks straight forward .... perhaps you could wire some switches  together

Comment: how to? don't know which switch does what, the controller has some silkscreen labels for the pins, but they are vaguely labelled. I have momentarily on switches or just use wire for that.

Comment: no matter how vague the labeling may be, it should be included in your question above ... a clear photo of the labeling would be best

Comment: i just looked at the datasheet that you included ... the control board connector pinout is on one of the pages ... the switches are connected between inputs and ground .... connect a wire to ground and touch the switch pins ... it should be easy to figure out which pin does what

Comment: Thanks! The datasheet pinout and the one on controller I have are different. Datasheet one has few more key pins than mine. I didn't know how to wire a switch between those pins, but I just had to short the ground and source. I started shorting "menu" and "ground", then all others. Although the pin that worked had "source" labelled in silkscreen but I didn't know it meant video source. Jut short the source pin to ground it cycles video source, on mine it is VGA, HMDI, AV1, AV2. Thanks!

Comment: you can compile the information about which pin does what and post an answer .... you can then "accept" your own answer